# Перечислить все разбиения натурального числа на натуральные слагаемые

Tags: c

У меня есть код, но он работает неправильно. Я так понимаю, что нужно делать рекурсией. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. То есть если на входе 4, на выходе должно быть 1+1+1+1, 1+1+2, 1+3, 2+2, 4 или в любом другом порядке. Знак "+" не обязателен при выводе. Я написал код, но он не выдает разбиение на все 1 и на 1+2. Ну, их я могу забить и вручную. А еще, начиная с 7 в разложении появляется разложение на 3 + 3, например, что неверно:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

F(int k, int n)  // Разбиение числа n на к слагаемых
{ int i;
  if (k==1) {
   printf("%d\n", n);
   return;
 }
  for(i=1; i<n-k; i++) {
   printf("%d ", i);
   F(k-1, n-i);
  }
}
main()
{ int i, N;
   scanf("%d", &N);
   for(i=N; i>0; i--)
     F(i, N);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    private static int p[]= new int[1000];

    private static void part(int L){
        if(L!=1){
            int i = L-2;
            int S = p[L-1];
            while( i > 0 && p[i] == p[i-1]){
                S+=p[i];
                i--;
            }
            p[i]++;
            L = i + S;
            for(int j = i + 1; j < L; j++)
                p[j]=1;
            for(int j=0;j<L;j++)
                System.out.print(p[j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
            part(L);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            p[i] = 1;
            System.out.print(p[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        part(n);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Например для 7:

- 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
- 2 1 1 1 1 1
- 2 2 1 1 1
- 2 2 2 1
- 3 1 1 1 1
- 3 2 1 1
- 3 2 2
- 3 3 1
- 4 1 1 1
- 4 2 1
- 4 3
- 5 1 1
- 5 2

Comment: Хм. А где `6 + 1`?

Comment: извините, не владею с++, мне бы реализацию кода на си